# Help me to calculate Heaps Alpha value from the roary pangenome pipeline result?

Tags: sequence-alignment, gene, genome, phylogeny, genomics

I need to know whether my `pan-genome` is `open or closed`. For that, I need to calculate the `Heaps Alpha value` from my [roary pipeline](https://sanger-pathogens.github.io/Roary/) results. Please help me to do the same.

Many thanks in advance.

---

Directly quoting from the link provide:

Roary By Andrew Page based on version 3.11.2 (22-Jan-2018)

Roary is a high speed stand alone pan genome pipeline, which takes annotated assemblies in GFF3 format (produced by Prokka (Seemann, 2014)) and calculates the pan genome. Using a standard desktop PC, it can analyse datasets with thousands of samples, something which is computationally infeasible with existing methods, without compromising the quality of the results.

Comment: I edited the question to give details of Roary. I personally find the context difficult to follow and further details would be helpful, such as the aim of the project as well as the genomes being used.

Comment: If this is a homework question (or otherwise canned question with a known answer), could you please tag as 'homework'? Also, please provide additional context around what you're trying to do (e.g. sample type, project goal).